# Planning upgrades of products with dependencies

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of deployed products $A$, $B$, $C$, ... Each product has a set of releases $A_1$, $A_2$, ... Right now suppose I am deploying the first release of each product. I would like to try to upgrade to the latest release of each product, if possible. Each product release can potentially depend on some range of releases of another product, e.g. $A_3$ might require that some release $B_n$ where $n \ge 4$ is deployed. If $B$ is currently on version 3 then I cannot upgrade $A$ to $A_3$ — I need to first upgrade $B$ to $B_4$ or higher (assuming that itself does not violate any constraints). I can only upgrade a single product at a time. We can assume that there are no cycles in these dependencies. Some questions I have:

- It's clear that even without circular dependencies there might not be any upgrade path, e.g. if the only constraints are $A_1$ requires $B_1$ and $A_2$ requires $B_2$, then I cannot reach $A_2$ and $B_2$. Can I efficiently determine whether there is any valid upgrade path to the latest release of each product?
- Can I efficiently determine the smallest number of upgrades I have to perform in order to reach the latest release of each product?
- Slightly more open-ended: is there possibly some more general version of this problem that I can read about? I'm very curious about it but I don't want to clutter my post with too many questions, so I would love to read a more thorough discussion of this problem if possible.

Comment: Are upgrades strictly overwriting previous versions or not? E.g., is it possible to have $B_1$ and $B_2$ simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, upgrades overwrite versions and only one version of a product is deployed at once.